# How to switch between two single file component in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I want to switch between two single file component in vuejs, i don't how to use attach and detach functions

Comment: I am very new to vuejs, just want to know how we can switch between two single file component within a single parent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mount dynamically single file component in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43799416/how-to-mount-dynamically-single-file-component-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`component`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#component) which is a built in component provided by vue.

## HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <h3>Parent component</h3>
  <button @click="current= 'ComponentA'">Show component A</button>
  <button @click="current= 'ComponentB'">Show component B</button>
  <component :is="current"></component>
</div>
```

## script

```
const ComponentA ={
  template:"<h4>This is component A</h4>"
}

const ComponentB ={
  template:"<h4>This is component B</h4>"
}

new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    current: "ComponentA"
  },
  components:{
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB
  },

})
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3qpgcka/5/)